# How to Write Asp.net code behind bootstrap modal submit button

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-modal

I want to add **Asp.net** code behind the submit button of this modal button,
if it is possible to change this submit button to **asp.net** button?

This is the image of bootstrap modal:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible and use these attributes to Button `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`, `data-dismiss="modal"`:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit"
    UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal" />
```